# Labeling rows via kbordermatrix

Tags: matrices

I would like to modify this matrix in such a way that the labels of the rows are on the right side rather than on the left side. Do you know how to do that?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,kbordermatrix,amsthm,amssymb,rotating,array}
\begin{document}

 \begin{eqnarray*}

  \mathbf{D}=\kbordermatrix{
    & t_1 & t_2 & t_3 & t_4 & t_5 \\
    t_1 & 0 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 2 \\
    t_2 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 3 \\
    t_3 & 3 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 3 \\
    t_4 & 3 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 2 \\
    t_5 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 2 & 0
  }

 \end{eqnarray*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `eqnarray` environment shouldn't be used any more. It gives bad spacings. Use the amsmath `align` environment, which has a simpler syntax.

Answer (score 4):

You can obtain this layout easily with `blkarray`:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,blkarray, bigstrut}

\begin{document}

 \[ \mathbf{D}= \begin{blockarray}{*{6}{>{\scriptstyle}c}}
       t_1 & t_2 & t_3 & t_4 & t_5\\
        \begin{block}{[ccccc] >{\scriptstyle}c}
         \bigstrut[t] 0 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 2 & t_1 \\
          2 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 3 & t_2 \\
          3 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 3 & t_3 \\
          3 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 2 & t_4 \\
          2 & 3 & 3 & 2 & 0 & t_5 \\
        \end{block}
      \end{blockarray}\]%

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with `{bNiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

 \[ \mathbf{D}= 
\begin{bNiceMatrix}[first-row,last-col=6,code-for-first-row=\scriptstyle,code-for-last-col=\scriptstyle]
t_1 & t_2 & t_3 & t_4 & t_5\\
0 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 2 & t_1 \\
2 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 3 & t_2 \\
3 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 3 & t_3 \\
3 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 2 & t_4 \\
2 & 3 & 3 & 2 & 0 & t_5 \\
\end{bNiceMatrix}\]
          
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]